# How do I avoid API limits during data migration?

Tags: api, limits

We are doing a data migration to salesforce involving millions of records. We use [Informatica Power Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informatica#Architecture), and we are querying data from an external database and inserting and updating records in Salesforce. We are running into API limits. What have others done to overcome the API limits during heavy data load scenarios?

Comment: Which API limits in particular are you running into? e.g. Apex triggers making too many SOQL queries or retrieving too many query rows?

Answer (score 5):

In your situation, you should be able to file a case with Salesforce to have your limits temporarily increased for the duration of the migration. Clearly, all you need is an adjustment while you're doing the migration. I'm confident they should be able to accommodate you.

Comment: It is the api limits per day request which has the problem..

Comment: We messed up our Informatica settings once in a data migration and opened a SF support Case. They temporarily increased the limit; we set it to use the batch API (duh!) and we were able to get the job done without waiting for the 24hr limit to roll over.

Comment: @buyankumar See [175738](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000175738&language=en_US) for details on how to request a *temporary* increase in your limits (up to two weeks).